# Custom eclipse plugin not selecting currently loaded project in navigator.

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have made a plugin for eclipse that imports projects. I wish to make it so that the newly imported project will be selected by default when the import successfully completes. I do not know how to fire a selection event on the newly imported project.

Comment: Ummm, could you clarify a bit more? What plugin in are you using? What do you mean my plugin selection event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
BasicNewResourceWizard.selectAndReveal(resource, workbenchWindow);
```

To select any resource.

In your case `resource` would be the `IProject` you have created.